# MD5 SHA512Managed c# conversion to Java code

Tags: java, c#, android, md5, sha512

I need help to convert this code to Java for password comparison and it must run on Android.
I am specially confused in how to add the salt given in this C# Code here:

## Code C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace CMS.Core.Utility
{
    public sealed class CMSHashManager
    {
        private static readonly string _salt = "3D5900AE-111A-45BE-96B3-D9E4606CA793";
        private static readonly int _hashIterationsMax = 10;
        private CMSHashManager()
        {
        }

        #region Public Methods
        //Gets the salted hash value with predetermined iterations.
        public static string GetPasswordHash(string plaintextPassword)
        {
            string hashData = plaintextPassword;
            for (int hashLimit = 0; hashLimit < _hashIterationsMax; hashLimit++)
                hashData = GetHash(_salt + hashData);
            return hashData;
        }

        //Verifies the hash
        public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string plaintextPassword, string encryptedPassword)
        {
            string hashData = GetPasswordHash(plaintextPassword);
            return encryptedPassword.Equals(hashData);
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods
        //Gets the hash value of the data using SHA512Managed
        private static string GetHash(string unhashedData)
        {
            byte[] hashData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unhashedData);
            // on server 2003 or higher, can use SHA512CryptoServiceProvider         
            //SHA512CryptoServiceProvider sha512CryptoServiceProvider = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();

            SHA512Managed sha512CryptoServiceProvider = new SHA512Managed();
            hashData = sha512CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(hashData);
            sha512CryptoServiceProvider.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashData);
        }
        #endregion Private Methods

    }

}
```

I have already written this java method which creates a MD5 hash:

## Code Java

```
public String getMD5Password(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512"); 
    digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-16LE")); 
    byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

    // Create Hex String
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
        String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
        while (h.length() < 2)
            h = "0" + h;
        hexString.append(h);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}
```

## Test

For testing purposes you can use the following case:

plaintext:`12345`
Encrypted:`NgkuakH7UsCQwGHMQOhVXI3nW6M+1AtREY4Qx35osQo87p/whZIzy8cZU7+R7XnmyzgMzLWSvX+rTiW‌​‌​zfGTPsA==`

Comment: Can you replace the C# code by something secure? It has two huge flaws: 1) No proper salt. You need a unique salt per-user, not a hardcoded global value. 2) 10 iterations is a joke. You should have at minimum 10000, preferably more.

Comment: I also recommend using a standard password hash such as PKBDF2 or bcrypt. Then you simply need to find an implementation of that standard in both languages instead of porting that crap.

Comment: Give us test values so that we can proof the validity of your/our code!

Comment: @Markus This is the real String for password (12345): "NgkuakH7UsCQwGHMQOhVXI3nW6M+1AtREY4Qx35osQo87p/whZIzy8cZU7+R7XnmyzgMzLWSvX+rTiW‌​zfGTPsA==" However what I am getting from your logic is this: "NUE3QkM2RkNFODAyRTZERUQ3QzBCQzA2Q0E2NzU0OEQzREUwNDg3M0FFQzgyMkY5QTIyMkRCNjBGRjg‌​3MjYxRUIyOTBGMDNDMzc5RkFEQTMxRTFDRjU1NEFCOEI2NEUwNThEOEEzMDM1MjkyQjQ5RUMzRTk0QUUy‌​NDM2MkQ3RUQ=" I will surely accept your answer and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for your update. C# logic is the one which I received from my Client. It is not likely that they will change it now.

Comment: I can confirm that the current code produces a valid result. I will change it to fit the Android environment.

Comment: @Markus Thanks for all your help but its NOT working. I need to get the final result this: NgkuakH7UsCQwGHMQOhVXI3nW6M+1AtREY4Qx35osQo87p/whZIzy8cZU7+R7XnmyzgMzLWSvX+rTiW‌‌​​zfGTPsA== for the password String password = "12345";

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your code.

For the password *test* it produces the following BASE64 output

`Q0Y2QkI0MTBFRUJFOTAyNkU1OUZGMUNGMzU0NkYzMkI3NDZFMzE5RjQzNTc0MDM5QjU2MUI2NEQxOTQzNzRGMDRENDM0QzMyQjg3MjMwQkM1N0I0ODFDRDlEODlBNjMxQjMyNjRGQjNBQjAwMEYwNjk5Rjc0NUNEQjgzMzY1RkM=`

I used the following code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

//import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import android.util.Base64;


public class Support {

    private static final String SALT = "3D5900AE-111A-45BE-96B3-D9E4606CA793";
    private static final int MAX_HASH_ITERATIONS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String result = Support.GetPasswordHash("test");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String GetPasswordHash(String plaintextPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String hashData = plaintextPassword;
        for (int hashLimit = 0; hashLimit < MAX_HASH_ITERATIONS; hashLimit++) {
            hashData = GetHash(SALT + hashData);
        }
        return hashData;
    }

    //Gets the hash value of the data using SHA512Managed
    private static String GetHash(String unhashedData) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return getMD5Password(unhashedData);
    }

    //Verifies the hash
    public static boolean VerifyHashedPassword(String plaintextPassword, String encryptedPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String hashData = GetPasswordHash(plaintextPassword);
        return encryptedPassword.equals(hashData);
    }


    public static String getMD5Password(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512"); 
        digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-16LE")); 
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int iPos = 0; iPos < messageDigest.length; iPos++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[iPos]);
            while (h.length() < 2) {
                h = "0" + h;
            }
            sb.append(h);
        }

        String md5String = sb.toString().toUpperCase();     
        String res = Base64.encodeToString(md5String.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: DatatypeConverter and the import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter; is not found is the error i am getting. Can you also please tell me wher to find this library. Thanks.

Comment: I am implementing the code for Android, so it is also possible that this library may not support. Please let me know what are your suggestions or if there is any alternative.

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer first? I will improve it so that it runs on Android.

Comment: This is the real String for password (12345):  "NgkuakH7UsCQwGHMQOhVXI3nW6M+1AtREY4Qx35osQo87p/whZIzy8cZU7+R7XnmyzgMzLWSvX+rTiWzfGTPsA==" However what I am getting from your logic is this: "NUE3QkM2RkNFODAyRTZERUQ3QzBCQzA2Q0E2NzU0OEQzREUwNDg3M0FFQzgyMkY5QTIyMkRCNjBGRjg3MjYxRUIyOTBGMDNDMzc5RkFEQTMxRTFDRjU1NEFCOEI2NEUwNThEOEEzMDM1MjkyQjQ5RUMzRTk0QUUyNDM2MkQ3RUQ="                                                  I will surely accept your answer and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For now I gave you +1 on your answer.

Comment: @HishamMuneer: Do you mind trying the new code snippet with out references to `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` but `android.util.Base64`?

Comment: Thanks for all your help but its working the same. I need to get the NgkuakH7UsCQwGHMQOhVXI3nW6M+1AtREY4Qx35osQo87p/whZIzy8cZU7+R7XnmyzgMzLWSvX+rTiW‌​zfGTPsA== for the password String password = "12345";

Comment: Thanks for all your help but its NOT working the same. I need to get the final result this: NgkuakH7UsCQwGHMQOhVXI3nW6M+1AtREY4Qx35osQo87p/whZIzy8cZU7+R7XnmyzgMzLWSvX+rTiW‌‌​​zfGTPsA== for the password String password = "12345";